# What is this large bushy plant, found in Somaliland?

Tags: identification, shrubs, desert

Please help me to identify this shrub. It's commonly found here in [Somaliland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somaliland).

[image]

Comment: COuld you add some more information, e.g. where and when you took the photo? Ad additional photo on leaves and spikes is also useful.

Comment: Its impossible to see the leaf structure, please add a photo showing a closeup of leaves and branches

Comment: Someone inform me... Acacia bussei.... The variety of nature is amazing here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you live in Australia?  Without seeing the leaves (small), the flowers, there are some pods in the picture when we enlarge my guess is Acacia kempeana...Wanderrie Wattle.

Answer (score 1):

I think this tree is *Acacia bussei*.

Comment: Hi amaj. It's fascinating to me how hard tree identifications are. I'm glad you found out from someone who knows! When I looked at the pictures at [Trees that grow in Somaliland](https://www.somalinet.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=331290#p4025637), yours looks more bushy and close to the ground. Maybe it's young, though and will look different as it grows. To me it looks more like a Foox (Somali) - Commiphora tree. There's a picture of that on the same page. There are a lot of interesting trees where you live!